# Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework for Material Button

Tags: android, material-ui, materialbutton

I am using the material button as

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/likeButton"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Filled"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialButton"
    android:insetLeft="0dp"
    android:insetRight="0dp"
    app:cornerRadius="2dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_like"
    app:rippleColor="@color/transparentColor"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_min="38dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="38dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>
```

In the logcat I am getting the following warning error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040180 a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:459)
at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:159)
at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:124)
at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:103)
at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:262)
at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:236)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:557)
at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:179)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:66)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:86)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:228)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:224)
```

Comment: have you figured out the reason?

Comment: @Amos nothing found yet

Answer (score 2):

Found out the reason is due to the app `Theme`, in your theme XML, the inherit parent shall be under `Theme.Material3.Xxx`, for me:

```
parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```